# Access View - Export to database failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Access Services are active for the site and site collection in SharePoint 2010. MS Access is installed at notebook of the user. When the user clicks at Access View in List Views, the message appears : « Export to database failed. To export a list, you must have a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application »
Any ideas on what could be the reason for this message ? Has anybody solved such issue in the past ?